# Is there a reason that `Functor` is not a superclass of `Category`?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory, category-abstractions

It seems you can simply declare:

```
import qualified Control.Category as Cat
instance Cat.Category q => Functor (q r) where
     fmap = (Cat..)
```

Is there anything speaking against this?

Comment: That definition doesn't even type check. remember that `(.) :: Category cat => cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c`, while `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That instance would overlap with many other useful instances, e.g. one could no longer add

```
instance Functor (State s) where ...
```

for the `State s` monad.